# retornar uma lista dos números que estão em sequência

Tags: python, lista

Estou tentando fazer com que uma lista qualquer seja percorrida e retorne uma outra com os números que estão em sequência.

Minha lista está retornando vazia.

Ex: `lista=[1,2,3,5,9,10]` retorna `nova_lista=[1,2,3,9,10]`

```
sequencial= []
def seq (lista):
     for i in range(0,len(lista)-1):
         if lista[i] == lista[i+1]:
             sequencial.append[i]
     return sequencial
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que `if lista[i] == lista[i+1]` compara se o elemento é igual ao próximo. E como a lista não tem elementos repetidos, o resultado sempre será vazio (pois nunca entrará nesse `if`).

Uma solução seria percorrer a lista a partir do segundo elemento e verificar se ele é igual ao "anterior + 1":

```
lista = [1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 10]
result = []
in_seq = False
for i in range(1, len(lista)):
    if lista[i] == lista[i - 1] + 1:
        if not in_seq:
            result.append(lista[i - 1])
            in_seq = True
        result.append(lista[i])
    else:
        in_seq = False

print(result)
```

Também usei a variável `in_seq` para saber se estou no meio de uma sequência, pois caso não esteja, eu também tenho que incluir o elemento anterior no resultado.

O resultado é:

```
[1, 2, 3, 9, 10]
```

Comment: Perfeito, consegui entender tudo que foi explicado.